# Obfuscate python eggs

Tags: python, obfuscation

I've got a nice python egg packaged as per usual with setuptools. Something like this

```
setup(
    name="my-egg-name",
    version="1.2.3",
    packages=['my.package','.'])
```

I also found this python obfuscator / minifier called [pyminifier](https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/). Is there a way in setuptools to run this "on the fly"? Plan B is to have a separate build step that first processes all python code and creates new folders with obfuscated modules, and then pack the egg.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide two answers:
(1) based on my reading of the software documentation
(2) based on different software where I have personally tested the latest version in production and worked with other people using it in production.

1. According to the pyminifer documentation at https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/ , pyminifier is supposed to support your Plan B to at least some extent (only a single directory is shown in the main page's example):

   "Pyminifier can also work on a whole directory of Python scripts:"

   `$ pyminifier --destdir=/tmp/minified_pyminifier pyminifier/*.py`

   If pyminifier works ok on your code, there is at least some support for your Plan B.
2. The Python obfuscator that I usually use for production code, the BitBoost python code obfuscator (http://bitboost.com/python-obfuscator), definitely supports your Plan B as its normal mode.

Disclaimer: Although I am the author of the BitBoost python obfuscator, use it for some of my own projects, and provide the tech support to various customers using it, I am striving to be fair in providing this answer.